# JSON_Normalize nested dictionary - some keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've been reading so much about json_normalize and trying so many things. I've been through the other json_normalize info on stacked_overflow and been reading through examples, but I just don't know how to get the output I want.

This is a subset of my JSON file:

```
     'sales': 114812.79,
     'sumOfSquares': 19528485.2151}},
   'timeToConversion': {'totals': {'sumOfSquares': 113163924542924.0,
     'total': 88221776.0}},
   'visit': {'totals': {'conversions': 2234, 'entries': 93297}},
   'visitor': {'totals': {'conversions': 2207, 'entries': 60236}}}}]
```

I need the row names to be the experience LocalID and the column names to be impression.conversions, impressions.entries, landing.conversions, landing.entries, so on. I only really need impressions, landings, visit, and visitor. I don't need to loop through the orders dictionary. Something like this:

[image]

When I try to do

`results = json_normalize(data = newdata, record_path="totals)"`

I just get a list of "impression", "landing", so on. I tried to go deeper, but I need a way to loop through this, because the names "impression", "landing" might change in future files.

Comment: `json_normalize(data)` works for me.

Comment: I tried it again, and I get one row with 31 columns. And the information I need is still nested within the column cells.